# Create variables accessible in info.plist

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded to RN0.30-rc and I noticed that there is new info.plist variable that needs to be set to be able to make network calls outside of localhost:

App Transport Security Settings

Now, setting this manually is easy enough, but i would like to keep things a little easier to maintain, particularly since info.plist is frequently overriden during upgrades.

Is there a way to reference a variable that I defined in an external properties file here?